# How can I structure this class so I can do as much unit testing as possible?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Good evening,

I am working to get my head around unit testing and I'm having a little trouble determining how far I can push unit testing before it turns into integration testing.

An example from the project I'm working on now: it has a class that performs LDAP searches against Active Directory using DirectorySearcher and returns the results as Person objects.  My first inclination was to grab the interface for DirectorySearcher and then create a fairly sophisticated stub that I can use for testing.  However, that proved problematic because DirectorySearcher doesn't seem to use an interface and it would require a lot of code to stub it out successfully.

My next thought was to create an Searcher class that internally uses DirectorySearcher, which would let me test the mapping between the LDAP results and the Person object mapping, but that doesn't gain me very much and it's yet another level of abstraction.

So I guess the bottom line is this: is there a way structure this so I can do most of my work with unit testing?  I'd really rather keep the integration test suite as small as possible, since I have to do the testing against an external data source that keeps changing.  I suspect there's a pattern for doing this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection :P (I know this isn't helpful, but a sentence in your question reminded me of this quote).

Comment: @Martin ... "Except for the problem of too many layers of indirection"  (thanks David Wheeler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a class that you can't dependency inject, then the best pattern would be to create a wrapper object and wrap that object. Then, you can inject your wrapper (or mock of the wrapper) to gain that functionality.

So in your case, you were correct to create a wrapper "Searcher" class that internally calls DirectorySearcher. Whatever methods you need to call on the DirectorySearcher, you provide as virtual methods on your Searcher class. Then you can create a mock searcher class with overriden methods and inject that when unit testing (Or, have Moq create it for you!)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that.  One of the things I'm struggling with most is when to create a seam and unit test as opposed to just throwing in the towel and doing integration testing.  Do you have any rough guidelines that you would recommend?

Comment: Basically, when you have some kind of operation that crosses the boundary of your application, then I usually wrap it if it's can't be injected. AKA, File IO, Web Calls, OS Level stuff. If you call out to something you didn't write, it's usually a good idea to wrap imo.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, your class (let's name it "PeoplePerson" for sake of discussion) needs to grab/reach people based on certain criteria. So its safe to say your class needs a PeopleRepository. We'll worry about how PeopleRepository is able to service calls like 'GetPeople(criteria)' later. Now if you test drive the development of PeoplePerson, you'd soon discover the right interface members (and they generally tend to be technology/impl. agnostic). Use a mocking framework (I'm assuming LDAP would make your unit tests slower) to inject a mock into PeoplePerson

> public PeoplePerson(IPeopleRepository
>   repository) {... //cache it}

Now figure out how each method on the IPeopleRepository can be implemented. Write tests for PeopleRepository that work against a real ActiveServer/LDAP provider wrapping a known dataset. These tests will be slow (integration tests that test integration with the ActiveServer) but they free everyone else from worrying about LDAP/ActiveServer.

I find creating that abstraction a good investment.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own interface for the Searcher, than you'll wrap your Searcher object in a class that implement it, this way you'll be able to dependency inject your stub, or mock.